# Why is curl not working when I attempt to retrieve the email address of an individual from LinkedIn

Tags: curl, get, zsh, linkedin-api, email-address

I am currently working on an app that allows users to sign in through LinkedIn. I would like to get the user's email and am currently testing it through terminal using curl first. From LinkedIn's API documentation I am aware that I need to GET from this url:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))
```

to get the email of a user. I have already requested permission from my user for retrieving their email address. The curl command I run is as follows:

```
curl https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~)) -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token"
```

where access_token in reality is the actual access token. However every time I run this on terminal I always get this response:

```
[1] 31166
zsh: no matches found: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members
zsh: unknown file attribute: h
[1]  + exit 1     curl https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members
```

This is odd considering that my request to:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
```

works perfectly fine. Does anyone know what might be a potential cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` in the URL is being parsed as a shell operator, running `curl` in the background. You need to escape it, which is most easily done by quoting the entire URL.

```
curl 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))' \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token"
```

---

More completely, after the `&` is parsed as a command terminator, you have the following two commands:

```
curl https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members & 
projection=(elements*(handle~))' -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token"
```

In both cases, you have characters that result in `zsh` attempting filename generation.

1. `?` in the first one
2. `*` in the second

The first command runs in the background, and immediately fails, because `zsh` treats an unmatched pattern as an error, not literal text like `bash` does by default.

The second command fails before a match is even attempted. The `(` introduces a series of glob qualifiers, but `h` is not a recognized qualifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot, is it always the case that when a url contains & you need to quote the entire url?

Comment: You need to quote anything the shell might treat specially. There are actually three separate errors in this case: the `&` splits your command line into two separate commands. The `?` produces the first non-match error, because `zsh` treats failed pattern matches as an error by default, rather than falling back on treating the pattern as literal text. The `*` in the second portion also causes the portion following `&` to be treated as a pattern, but before a match is even attempted, the `h` following the first `(` is treated as a glob qualifier, but there is no such qualifier in `zsh`.